# Iterators in java - remove numbers in a range

Tags: java, iterator, range, between

I'm trying to remove numbers from a LinkedList using an iterator. 
I can't get it to remove numbers from only between to variables.

My list contains these values: 1, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 8, 8, 3, 11, 9, 12, 0, 14, 0, 16]

The call of the method 
`removeEvenInRange(list,5,13)`    should remove the even numbers between index 5 and 13, ending up with a list containing 
`[1,1,2,0,4,5,3,11,9,0,14,0,16`

I don't know how to "tell" it to only iterate between the indexes 5 - 13. Any help on how to solve this would be much appreciated.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class Ex11_3_RemoveEvenInRange {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(1,1,2,0,4,5,6,8,8,3,11,9,12,0,14,0,16));

    removeEvenInRange(list, 5, 13);
}

private static void removeEvenInRange(List<Integer> list, int i, int j) {


            Iterator<Integer> itr = list.iterator();

            for (int k = i; k < j; k++) {

                int element = itr.next();

                if (element % 2 == 0) {
                    itr.remove();

                }
            }


                System.out.println(list);

    }
}
```

Comment: why do you even use an iterator if you can simply access the elements directly via the List API?

Comment: What about `for(i=5; i<=13;i++) { list.get(i); /* test for even */ }` do you not understand?

Comment: @Paul with an `Iterator` you don't need to worry about the list size (which will change by removing elements), and can simply loop using `while(iterator.hasNext())`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `subList` between two indexes. Try,

```
static void removeEvenInRange(List<Integer> list, int i, int j){

    List<Integer> subList= list.subList(i, j);
    Iterator<Integer> itr = subList.iterator();


    while (itr.hasNext()){
        int element = itr.next();
        if (element % 2 == 0) {
            itr.remove();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, unless you call `next()` n (5 in this case) times before running your code - which would be insane.

Your best option is probably to split your list into three [sublists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29), iterate over the middle one, and merge the lists after you're done.

Another approach would be using `get(index)` and `remove(index)` on the list directly, which saves the split/merge step, but you'll have to make sure you adjust the index for every remove. The split/merge approach is less error-prone.

edit: The Answer by @Masud has example code for this, although it's missing the merge step.

Comment: I'm not sure why it would be _insane_ to iterate until `fromIndex`.  It's surely more efficient than calling `LinkedList#remove(index)` repeatedly. But using a `sublist` and iterating on it is a good idea and may be the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

What your current implementation is doing is removing all even numbers from the list from index `0` through index `j - i - 1`, not `i` through `j - 1`.  The range is shifted because you're not iterating until `k` is in range.

Start your `for` loop at index `0`, so your index is consistent with the iterator's index.  Then add an `if` statement to determine if your index `k` is in the proper range between `i` and `j`.

```
for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
    int element = itr.next();

    if (k >= i && k < j)
    {
        if (element % 2 == 0) {
            itr.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need k < j in the if

Answer (score 0):

If you want use an iterator you can write something like:

```
 for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {

         int element = itr.next();
             if (k>=i) {
                    if (element % 2 == 0) {
                        itr.remove();
                       }
                   }

          }
```

but is more  efficient if you use [get(int index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int))

Comment: Not in case of a `LinkedList`: `get(int index)` is O(N).

Comment: He can use ArrayList implementation

Answer (score 0):

You will need to *count* and advance the iterator until you reach the start index. Then you continue counting in parallel of iterating and removing the elements you want to remove through the iterator, until the *count* reaches the end index.

If you stick to a `LinkedList`, the above process will be more efficient than removing through the `List#remove(index)` method (as suggested in some comments), since each call to remove will go through the list to find the index.